# Removing punctuation with an exception in python

Tags: python, string, nltk, punctuation

I am trying to remove punctuation from a given string in python.

It works well, however the data I am using includes lots of ":D" or ":)" or ":(".

Therefore when I analyse the data, I end up removing all of these text-smiles or only ":" for ":D"-case.

Following is an example code:

```
import string
import nltk

example_string = 'I would like to remove some punctiation, \
                  however some stuff like \':D\' causes errors. \
                  How would I not get rid of \':\', \
                  if it is followed by a \'D\'? '


translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)

line = example_string.translate(translator)
line = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
line = [word.lower() for word in line
                     if word not in ['\'', '’', '”', '“']]

print(line)
```

This produces as output:

```
['i', 'would', 'like', 'to', 'remove', 'some', 'punctiation',
 'however', 'some', 'stuff', 'like', 'd', 'causes', 'errors',
 'how', 'would', 'i', 'not', 'get', 'rid', 'of', 'if', 'it',
 'is', 'followed', 'by', 'a', 'd']
```

What I would like to produce is **(check the second line 5th word)**:

```
['i', 'would', 'like', 'to', 'remove', 'some', 'punctiation',
 'however', 'some', 'stuff', 'like', ':d', 'causes', 'errors',
 'how', 'would', 'i', 'not', 'get', 'rid', 'of', 'if', 'it',
 'is', 'followed', 'by', 'a', 'd']
```

It will also remove all of ":)" or ":(".

**Is there a way to not remove ":", if it is followed by a "d"?**

**or not remove ")" or "(", if the previous character is ":" ?**

Comment: in regxp you can define such rules.

Comment: I am guessing it is a module in python like nltk? @LiorCohen

Comment: yes. `import re`

Comment: also if u new to regexp this is a great online tool for experimentation until you get the right query. https://regex101.com/

Comment: ty! for the help :)